# Sucuri saying that our website has an Issue 409 Conflict on contact page

Tags: security

I ran a test and found no vulnerabilities on my site except this warning:

https://www.bragdeal.com/contact/ 
Unable to scan the page. 409 Conflict

How can I fix it? I've researched online but all I found is the Wordpress CF7 is the cause but no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error code is common when user sends a PUT request but the server is not able to (or should not) process. This might be the reason in your case as contact page should not allow an user to add file/resource to it, and hence responding with 409 Conflict code.

Comment: So I can just ignore this or anything I should do?

Comment: @BragDeal Can't say for sure, but it looks like while testing, a malicious code/file was tried to be uploaded via PUT method. To this response, the server sends 409 Conflict. **Can be Ignored**.

Comment: Do you recommend any particular plugins to beef up the security? like sucuri plugin for example? or BBQ: Block Bad Queries

Comment: Yes, **Sucuri** is considered one of the test plugins available today. On top of that make sure you are yourself up-to-date in cybersecurity news.